# Changing XCode project name causes fatal error

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am trying to rename my XCode 4 project. I have tried several different ways, but nothing works. I always get the following error:

```
fatal: source directory is empty,
source=Desktop/Folder/OLD PROJECT NAME.xcodeproj,
destination=Desktop/Folder/NEW PROJECT NAME.xcodeproj
```

What's causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I was trying to rename a project for the second time. The error was "fatal: bad source ...".
The original project was called AppTemplate. The new project was called "Project1" (say). Project1 was created by doing a project rename (from the right bar) and subsequent steps (move main directory, change plist refs, rename scheme).
When i tried to rename the new project, it complained that AppTemplate.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/AppTemplate.xcscheme wasn't available. This is odd since i thought i eradicated all reference to the original project. Apparently not. 
My [hack] solution was to copy the original AppTemplate.xcscheme file from the original project into Project1 at the required location (Project1.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/). 
The project rename then proceeded as normal.
I know this was not your exact issue, but this is one of the few references to fatal errors on project rename on xcode.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this if the issues comes up again.

Comment: You know what... since this was the only relevant answer ever posted, I'll accept it as the correct answer. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:

1. Delete the .git folder from the project directory.
2. Now you get a different fatal error when you rename.
3. Go to File->Source Control->Repositories and delete the repository from the list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying, but this isn't a GIT issue. There's no GIT folder and no repository.

Comment: That worked for me. Would be nice if there was another way in case you needed to keep the git repo.

Comment: That might have worked for Steve, but it is definitely no answer to my question. So far this problem is unsolved.

Comment: It seemed only to work for me when I had no spaces in the project name. That could be the key, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and for me the problem was that the project I was trying to rename was *not* in a git repository, i.e. git saw it as a bunch of untracked files.

Adding the files to git (and committing) fixed the problem, I was able to rename the project.

It looks like Xcode 4 really wants your project files to be in a git repository.

Comment: Hi. I want to make clear that both answers given here are COMPLETELY IRRELEVANT!!!! My question has absolutely nothing to do with GIT. Thanks.