# Changing project identity and type in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist, xcode-project

I have a working iOS application in Xcode, and wanted to change the display name of the application on the phone. When i click on the main project directory in Xcode, a menu opens on the right side of the screen. Under the title "Identity and Type", I tried to change the name to something different. When prompted, I chose to change the references in other files. Now, my file has an error, because my -info.plist file no longer exists (because the project is apparently trying to reference the plist file sharing the original name of my application). When I tried to simply change the name back to the previous one, I get an error that says

```
"OldProjectName.xcodeproj" couldn't be moved to "ios" because an item with the 
same name already exists. To save the file, either provide a different name, 
or move aside or delete the existing file, and try again.
```

I realize this problem is likely trivial, but i'm not entirely familiar with Xcode and i'm concerned that I will delete or move an essential file. For some reason, although I enabled them, I don't have any screenshots I can revert back to. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming projects in Xcode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Not a duplicate, read the whole question there is more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error, change the name of the project (which is what you changed) back to what it was originally. To answer your question, to change the display name go to the info.plist and change the "bundle display name" to whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you for your response @WyattMufson . I tried to change the name of the project back, and I get the error I posted above. For whatever reason, it wont let me rename it? Unless there is some other way to rename the project

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819915/changing-xcode-project-name-causes-fatal-error

Comment: that did the trick! For some reason my Scheme was only showing "my mac", so I had to tweak that too. I ended up simply changing the name as I had already done to some third option, then returning to the original one and it worked. Go figure! Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, please vote up my answer / choose it!